# db design: Two "1 to many" relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

In my situation i have

```
 TABLE vehicles (
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   transaction_type varchar(45),
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   /* all other values of vehicle */
 ) 


 TABLE Origination(
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) 

 TABLE Additions(
   id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
```

So i have this new vehicles table that originate either from Origination, or Additions. The reason it can come from two tables is business needs, it either orginates for the origin or it originates from a special addition after the fact. I'm unsure how to connect a "vehicle" relation to both tables as the id can come from either.

So i added a transaction_type field, where if type is "Additions" join tables based on Additions Id. Else if type is "origination" join on Origination Id.
So i  have a Two Key "1 to many" relationship. is this a valid and useable design practice? I am not a database person, but am trying to learn how to handle this is the best way.

Comment: From what I understand of the question... it may be best to have 2 different intermediary tables: vehicles_Origination and vehicles_Additions to connect the three tables. I'm not sure if this is what you're after. vehicles_Origination would have vehicle_id and origination_id and you wouldn't need the transaction_type in this case which is good; I think that goes against design standard.

Comment: @JohnCullen Yeah that was my second strategy, was to have 2 relationship tables they connect the others too. I thought it may be convoluted having multiple tables as such, but it would work as well. I want to fluidly connect the tables in a best practice sense, or most optimal. I know the design isnt the best, but it's kind of what im stuck with.

Comment: @JohnCullen Actually semi confused on this. So i would have Vehicle_Additons table and Vehicle_origination table in place of vehicles table correct? And then those id's connect onto additions and originations table rather than join than join the two into one vehicles table

Comment: no, you would have a Vehicles table and then you'd have the Origination, and Additions table. To connect the Vehicles table and the other tables you'd need 2 relational tables: Vehicle_Origination and Vehicle_Addition. Vehicle_Origination would have a FK that references Vehicles and another that references the Additions table.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want a main table containing ALL your vehicles and two separate tables that add different data to those vehicles. This is how I'd make that work. If you be more specific about what each table does I can be of more help.

```
TABLE Vehicle (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    /* all other values of vehicle */
) 

TABLE Origination (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

TABLE Addition (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

TABLE Vehicle_Origination (
    origination_id int(11),
    vehicle_id int(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (origination_id) REFERENCES Origination (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES Vehicle (id)
) 

TABLE Vehicle_Addition (
    addition_id int(11),
    vehicle_id int(11),
    FOREIGN KEY (addition_id) REFERENCES Addition (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES Vehicle (id)
)
```

Comment: Okay, so there is a user. When he first starts using the web application, he has vehicles he begins with. So he enters all the information for the vehicles and those all get added to vehicles at Origination table. Any transactions the user does after that to vehicles are processed through the additions table. I want to merge all the vehicles together into a vehicle table for query purposes , but unsure how to connect them back to their respective addition and origination table that contains transactional information as well, if needed. Btw Thanks for responding and helping out.

Comment: I can try answering more if you need more details.